# How can I get a list of the symbols in a sympy expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

For example, if I run

```
import sympy
x, y, z = sympy.symbols('x:z')
f = sympy.exp(x + y) - sympy.sqrt(z)
```

is there any method of `f` that I can use to get a list or tuple of `sympy.Symbol` objects that the expression contains? I'd rather not have to parse `srepr(f)` or parse downward through `f.args`.

In this case, `g.args[0].args[1].args[0]` gives me `Symbol("z")`, while `g.args[1].args[0].args` gives me the tuple `(Symbol("x"), Symbol("y"))`, but obviously these are expression-specific.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use:

```
f.free_symbols
```

which will return a set of all free symbols.

Example:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> x, y, z = sympy.symbols('x:z')
>>> f = sympy.exp(x + y) - sympy.sqrt(z)
>>> f.free_symbols
set([x, z, y])
```

Comment: Note that this only returns **free** symbols.  For example, for `Sum(T, (n, 1, N))/N` it returns `{N, T}`, but not `n`.

Answer (score 13):

A very useful attribute is `atoms`

```
x, y, z = sympy.symbols('x:z')
expr1 = sympy.exp(x + y) - sympy.sqrt(z)
display(expr1.free_symbols)
display(expr1.atoms(sympy.Symbol))

{,,} 
{,,}
```

In addition to symbols, `atoms` can extract other atoms, e.g.:

```
display(expr1.atoms(sympy.Function))
display(expr1.atoms(sympy.Number))
display(expr1.atoms(sympy.NumberSymbol))
display(expr1.atoms(sympy.function.AppliedUndef))
display(expr1.atoms(sympy.Mul))
display(expr1.atoms(sympy.Add))
```

(it's worth checking the output).
Regarding the [answer by gerrit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41763173/2707864)

```
n = sympy.Symbol('n')
k2 = sympy.Sum(x, (n, 0, 10))
display(k2.free_symbols)
display(k2.variables)
display(k2.atoms(sympy.Symbol))

{} 
[]
{,}
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that [JuniorCompressors answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30019034/974555) only lists **free variables**.

If you have a [`Sum`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/concrete.html#sympy.concrete.summations.Sum), a [`Product`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/concrete.html#sympy.concrete.products.Product), an [`Integral`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/integrals/integrals.html#sympy.integrals.Integral), or something similar, you may or may not want to additionally know the integration/summation variable using the `.variables` attribute:

```
In [216]: (x, n) = sympy.symbols("x n")

In [217]: f = sympy.Sum(x, (n, 0, 10))

In [218]: f.free_symbols
Out[218]: {x}

In [219]: f.variables
Out[219]: [n]
```

Comment: Note that the `variables`attribute is only available for these concrete expression types. For example, this fails: `f = sympy.Sum(x, (n, 0, 10)) * 2` because now `f` is of type `Mul`, which does not have the attribute.