# Extracting free symbols from a symbolic expression in sympy that was defined as a whole expression

Tags: python, sympy, symbols

Say I have two symbolic expressions:

```
a = symbols("a")
thing = symbols("2*a**2")
```

If one then calls `a.free_symbols()` one gets `{a}`, and for `thing.free_symbols()` one gets `{2*a**2}`.

Is there a way to format the object `thing` such that I get the equivalent expression but with `eq_expr.free_symbols() = {a}`?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018977/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-symbols-in-a-sympy-expression?

Comment: The question is unclear. If the existing answers are insufficient then explain more clealy what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that writing brackets in `a.free_symbols()` gives an error: `TypeError: 'set' object is not callable`.  [`free_symbols`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.free_symbols) is a *property* of an expression, not a *function*.

When you write `thing = symbols("2*a**2")` ([docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#symbols)), you create a new variable `thing`, whose **name** is `"2*a**2"` and which is not connected to `a` whatsoever.

You can write `thing = 2*a**2` (or `thing = sympify("2*a**2")` ([docs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#id1))) to make `thing` an expression using variable `a`. In that case, `thing.free_symbols` would be `{a}`.