# How do I access the variable x and y in an equation

Tags: geometry, sympy, equation

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve, Circle, Point, latex, simplify, sympify
x, y = symbols('x y')
m = Circle(Point(0, 0), Point(1, 0), Point(0, 2))
dt = m.equation()
dt = dt.subs(x,2)
print(dt)
```

The answer should be like be

```
k=(x - 1/2)**2 + (y - 1)**2 - 5/4
k = k.subs(x, 2)
print(k)
```

I tried to copy the whole block inside sympy lib but it got confused of the "_symbol". The type of `dt` is `<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>` but when open lib, I couldn't find `sympy.core.add.Add`.

I hope to change to value of `x` and `y` inside the equation so it would give the answer like the second line.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is.

Comment: I think you want to use `m.equation(x, y)`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `x` an `y` from a naive `Circle.equation()` are not the same `Symbol`s as you created (despite appearances), and you should either pass in the symbols as arguments or use the defaults and get them from the equation ([How can I get a list of the symbols in a sympy expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018977/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-symbols-in-a-sympy-expression) )

```py
>>> dt.free_symbols
{y, x}
>>> [sym is x for sym in dt.free_symbols]
[False, False]
```

Passing in the symbols

```py
>>> f = m.equation(x,y)  # quick access to docs via help(m.equation)
>>> f
(x - 1/2)**2 + (y - 1)**2 - 5/4
>>> f.subs({x:2, y:3})
5
>>> [sym is x for sym in f.free_symbols]
[False, True]
```

extracting them from it into a dict (ugly)

```py
>>> f = m.equation()
>>> f.free_symbols
{y, x}
>>> smb = {str(sym): sym for sym in f.free_symbols}
>>> smb
{'y': y, 'x': x}
>>> f.subs({smb["x"]:2, smb["y"]:3})
5
```

Finally, you could use [lambdify it](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html)

```py
>>> from sympy import lambdify
>>> f = m.equation()
>>> fn = lambdify(sorted(f.free_symbols, key=str), f)
>>> fn(x=1, y=3)
3.0
>>> fn(x=2, y=3)
5.0
```